# java.lang.AssertionError. How correctly fill an array through the loop. I do not know why my code does not work

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class CreateNewArray {
public static int[] createArray() {
int numbers[] = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
numbers[i] = i + 1;
}return numbers;
}
}
```

The code does not work, please, help me to fix it.

Comment: how you are calling `createArray` method, please share that

Comment: Hi& Welcome! Please better describe the problem/expectations! ..since the "array filling" "looks ok"

Answer (score -1):

Illegal modifier for the local class CreateNewArray; only abstract or final is permitted.

Well just remove the public.

```
class CreateNewArray {
  public static int[] createArray() {
    int numbers[] = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i + 1;
    }return numbers;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.